# Is having both mod_security and htmlpurifier an overkill?

Tags: php, security, htmlpurifier, owasp, mod-security

We had htmlpurifier integrated into our LAMP based product earlier, but it was a bit slow. Recently, we have turned on mod_security. Both of these are part of the OWASP project (owasp used htmlpurifer internally last I checked) so I am thinking the security is redundant.

What would you suggest? Is turning off htmpurifier a viable option? Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They both do different things. [`mod_security`](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_security) is a blacklist. It covers some generic exploits (among them XSS, SQL injection, directory traversals, url injection, and others) and past application bugs, but is likely easier to foil with more elaborate encodings and application-specific ways to circumvent the filters. (It often just probes for some URL parameters.)

[`HTMLPurifier`](http://www.google.com/search?q=HTMLPurifier) really only coveres HTML sanitization, but that it does quite well. It's a whitelist filter, so by definition more secure. It's of course slow. Which is why you should only apply it to incoming data, not as generic filter for everything and everywhere. If it slows down your application you are potentially using it in the wrong spots.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what you are saying is that since mod_security acts based on regexes, it is easier to break than the tokens based htmlpurifier? So, would it matter if we choose to remove mod_security and keep htmlpurifier? Thanks again.

Comment: I would not disable it. It causes me personally lots of trouble with false positives, but it's a significantly faster firewall against spam and xss attempts. I would not rely on it solely, but it reduces in-application checks and hence log entries. It does cause some server slowdown, but I think that's not significant enough. So keep it enabled unless you have a big site with too many concurrent users.